# PyQt GetDC operation failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Whenever running my PyQT Application, I get the following error

`QWindowsBackingStore::flush: GetDC failed (The operation completed successfully.)`

I do not see any other errors from my application. All I see is this message/error spamming my console and I am unable to debug this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

This error generally occurs after my program is running for few hours. Problem is its not reproducible on all the machines, and it happens at random intervals, not at any exact moment or after an error. I think GetDC is supposedly a windows call and it is failing, but what could be the possible reasons? PyQT does not show any stack trace or specific point where it seems to fail.
My Application is also using the camera, and while the application freezes, the python code at the backend keeps working.